# side by side fragments on tablet

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that displays a map. When a user presses one of the action bars another listview fragment appears showing a list of items.

I am trying to get the listview to appear on the left side of the map when the app is running on the tablet however I am running into difficulties.

I currently have one Activity which manages the fragments.

I have tried a solution that I found on StackOverflow however it doesn't work.

Here is the layout XML that is being used for both large and standard layouts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myFragment"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ViewGroup
    android:id="@+id/leftContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ViewGroup
    android:id="@+id/rightContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the onCreate code for the ACtivity:
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

ft.add(R.id.leftContainer, loadRoutesFragment);
ft.add(R.id.rightContainer, viewModeFragment);
ft.hide(loadRoutesFragment);
ft.commit();
```

I hide the loadRoutesFragment to begin with but when the button is pressed I use the show method which should make the Fragment appear.

The app crashes on `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
Here are the exceptions:

```
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.srose.cyclopathed/com.srose.cyclopathed.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.view.ViewGroup
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.view.ViewGroup
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at com.srose.cyclopathed.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    ... 11 more
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.view.ViewGroup
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-24 23:25:56.889: E/AndroidRuntime(20746):    ... 26 more
```

Anyone have any idea why?

Thanks

Current XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/leftContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/rightContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The LogCat reads:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.view.ViewGroup
```

Which means you cannot create a generic ViewGroup in your layout. A common alternative is to use a `<fragment />` element with the class in the `name` attribute or you can use specific ViewGroup like FrameLayout or LinearLayout. There are some examples in the Developer's Guide on [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: THanks for the reply. I changed the ViewGroup to fragment keeping the same parameters. It seems to be the same as the developers guide example however the same problem persists with the same exceptions except it cant inflate the class fragment

Comment: Please add your current XML to your question.

Comment: I am using ActionBarSherlocks SherlockFragment. Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: Shouldn't be, you haven't defined what fragment class you want to use. You must add: `android:name="com.srose.cyclopathed.LoadRoutesFragment"` and `android:name="com.srose.cyclopathed.ViewModeFragment"` (assuming those are the appropriate class names.)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work now.

One thing though. The left side panel is present even if I don't add the loadRoutesFragment. calling the hide method on it doesn't work either.

Do I need to specify something so that the side panel only appears when the button is pressed?

Comment: You need to change tactics, by using `<fragment />` you cannot replace or remove these fragments. However you can change the visibility to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE` to hide the fragment until later. You can actually remove all of you FragmentManager code from above.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without specifying the fragments in the xml file and just adding them in the code as I will need to be replacing fragments.

Comment: Yes, use a View like FrameLayout or something else. I sometimes use an empty RelativeLayout or LinearLayout and add the Fragments in with the FragmentManager.

Comment: ok, so do you mean, if I remove the two fragment elements out of the xml then when I want to add a Fragment would I just call: `ft.add(R.id.myFragment, loadRoutesFragment);` ?